# Conditionally close tag in Angular Ionic3 template

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to make a select list in angular template with the array below.

```
var arr = [
    {section:"An Hour before Dinner", title:"Cook peas"},
    {section:"An Hour before Dinner", title:"Take pie out"},
    {section:"As guests arrive", title:"Mix drinks"},
    {section:"Just Before Dessert", title:"Reheat at 325 about 20 minutes."},
    {section:"Just Before Dessert", title:"Cut and serve."}
];
```

I would like to have this kind of result in angular template:
https://jsfiddle.net/8n3vfgLr/
[image]

Comment: `ng-init` and `ng-if` are AngularJS directives. They are not part of Angular 3 and Ionic3.

Comment: For the error part, you have written </ion-select> part before then its initialization.

Comment: what you want to do? it looks syntax error.